# Default button in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, winrt-xaml

I am using the GroupedItemsPage.xaml. I have set the item source to List of Group where "Group" is my custom class which shows different groups with their items in it. My problem is that I want to add a "Add" button to each group so that each time a group is loaded, the "Add" button is shown irrespective of whether the group has items in it or not.[image]
The first image is how I want my group to look after adding some items. The second image is how I want my group to look when no items have been added. How do I proceed? I am using the following grid view style.

```
 <Style TargetType="GridView" x:Key="GridViewStyle">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="GridView">
                    <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer"
                                      TabNavigation="{TemplateBinding TabNavigation}"
                                      HorizontalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode}"
                                      HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                      VerticalScrollMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode}"
                                      VerticalScrollBarVisibility="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility}"
                                      IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalScrollChainingEnabled}"
                                      IsHorizontalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsHorizontalRailEnabled}"
                                      IsVerticalRailEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsVerticalRailEnabled}"
                                      ZoomMode="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.ZoomMode}"
                                      IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled}"
                                      BringIntoViewOnFocusChange="{TemplateBinding ScrollViewer.BringIntoViewOnFocusChange}">
                            <Grid Height="765" Width="2666" Margin="0">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <!-- Your custom buttons -->
                                <Grid x:Name="myGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="1108" DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" >
                                    <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                        <Image Source="Assets/Untitled.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
                                    </Border>
                                    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Top"  Height="755" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                                        <TextBlock Text="RoleCenter"   Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Height="77" Margin="140,50,0,0"/>
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding x}" Style="{StaticResource PageHeaderTextStyle}" Height="77" Margin="140,300"/>
                                    </StackPanel>

                                </Grid>


                                <ItemsPresenter
                                            HeaderTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}"
                                            Header="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                            HeaderTransitions="{TemplateBinding HeaderTransitions}"

                                            Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Margin="1113,10,244,0" />

                                <StackPanel Width="150" Height="150" Background="#006AC1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,100,0">
                                    <Button x:Name="LoadMore" Content="+" Height="150" Click="Navigate"  Width="150" />


                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the GridView is bound to a collection of ViewModels. Most people usually add a "blank/empty" ViewModel to each group of their collection and have the GridView swap out the template to use for rendering that ViewModel using an ItemTemplateSelector.

Take a look at SO question [WinRT gridview Add tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223958/winrt-gridview-add-tile) as a point of reference.  There is a great sample implementation shown there.

Here is also a video which shows this concept in action starting at 14:23 into the Video. http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Migrating-apps-from-Windows-Phone-to-Windows-8/Binding-the-Interface-in-Windows-Store-apps

Comment: Thanx :) That was exactly what I was looking for! I completed the task yesterday by adding an extra element to the DefaultViewModel but this solution is much better. Will try it now :)