# WinRT GridView with custom visual styles and add button

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

I try to build a GridView in a Window Store App that has an inline "Add" button at its end. I have implemented a dummy view model solution as described in [WinRT gridview Add tile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13223958/winrt-gridview-add-tile). Now I want the selected item use another template (for editing). I have implemented that using the Visual State Manager (by assigning a new `<ControlTemplate TargetType="SelectorItem">` in the style, which handles the `Selected` and `SelectedUnfocused` states). This also works. However, I cannot get the combination, because the `ItemTemplateSelector` uses a `DataTemplate` whereas I need a `ControlTemplate` for the VSM. What can I do?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`ItemContainerStyleSelector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyleselector.aspx?cs-lang=csharp).